# Mongoose array of Schema not saving anything beside id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating `blog` for teaching purposes. I want to have tags (optional). The problem is that it is creating new `TagSchema` but it saves only the `_id` in the db for the related post and not the name of the tag.

**PostSchema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Comment = require('./Comment'),
Tags = require('./Tag');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Author: String,
  Title: String,
  Description: String,
  Comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'   
  }],
  Tags: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag'
  }],
  CreatedOn: Date,
  LastEditOn: Date
});

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post');
```

**TagSchema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  TagName: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tag', TagSchema);
```

And in the `post` request

```
app.post('/post-add', isLogged, (req, res) => {
    // save new post
    var post = new Post();

    post.Author = req.user.username;
    post.Description = req.body.Description;
    post.Title = req.body.Title;
    post.CreatedOn = new Date();

    if (req.body.Tag.length > 0) {
        var tags = req.body.Tag.split(' ');

        tags.forEach((element, idx) => {    
            var tag = new Tag();
            tag.TagName = element;

            post.Tags.push(tag);
        });
    }

    post.save((err) => {
        if (err) return err;

        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: On a general note, avoid using capital letters for attributes names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it, depends on what you actually want.

If you don't need the generated `_id` for a `Tag`, you can set up your Tag model as :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tag', TagSchema);
```

This avoids creating duplicated tags.

If you still need an unique `_id`, then you need to create the tag first and save it :

```
var tag = new Tag();
tag.TagName = element;
await tag.save();
```

I would use `.findOneAndUpdate()` with an `.upsert()` instead of always creating a `new Tag()` in this case.
Then when you get the `Post`, use `.populate('Tags')` to get the tag names.

Comment: hmm.. how I'm supposed to save the tags with their names provided when creating post if I use `_id`? I don't want duplicates of course.

Comment: In your API, use ``findOneAndUpdate()`` function combined with ``upsert: true`` option. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878147/mongodb-and-mongoose-how-to-add-an-object-if-it-doesnt-already-exist for example